# What other browsers are available for iPad

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, web-browser

As the question says, what other web browsers are available on the iPad? 
I would ideally like Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Open software recommendations are not on-topic on Ask Different. You need to specify what you are looking for in an iPad browser. You could also make this community wiki, though there's a good possibility it could get closed.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question is too open-ended. If you have specific requirements, feel free to post a `software-recommendation` with those requirements. If you're looking to compile a list, it needs to be done in a more curated manner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Dolphin Browser](http://itunes.apple.com/en/app/dolphin-browser-for-ipad/id460812023?mt=8)

- Gestures: create a personal symbol to access the websites you use the most
- Visit your favorite sites with one touch.
- Tabbed browsing
- Bookmarks Bar
- Full Screen Mode

[image: App Store app page screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Chrome and Firefox are not available for the iPad. If you want an interface which looks like Chrome, you might like [Diigo Browser](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ichromy-chrome-style-web-browser/id432838105?mt=8#). Here's a [review of the app](http://ipadinsight.com/ipad-app-reviews/ichromy-chrome-style-web-browser-for-ipad) which may help.

[image]

You could search for "browser" on the app store, but realize that most of the applications that you find will still be using the same rendering engine that Apple developed. It's only the stuff around the rendering engine that will look different.

**Update: There is now a version of [Firefox](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/firefox-web-browser/id989804926?mt=8) for iOS.**

Answer (score 2):

Chrome and Firefox haven't been developed for iOS yet, but you could try Dolphin Browser. It's very similar to Chrome, and you can download extensions for it. Personally, Dolphin is my favorite. Opera Mini and Murcury Web Browser (quite similar to Desktop Safari) are another couple nice alternative to Mobile Safari, and Atomic Web Browser is slightly better than Safari, but doesn't have many features. If you want to watch Flash videos on your iPad, try out Skyfire. It's limited, but it does what it says. There are plenty more browsers out there for iOS, but these are the ones I use most.

**Update: There is now a version of [Firefox](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/firefox-web-browser/id989804926?mt=8) for iOS.**